# PHP date converting to timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I want to convert the php date to timestamp. But i'm getting same output even I change the date in my URL.

Example:  Imagine that I have URL that will get the value.

*url: `localhost/index.php?text_checkin=22/06/2018`*

```
$checkin = strtotime($_GET['text_checkin']);
$textin = date('y/m/d', $checkin);
echo $textin;
```

OUTPUT: `70/01/01`

Please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use `date_create_from_format` instead

working demo : https://eval.in/1018426

```
$checkin = $_GET['text_checkin'];

$dateObj = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y',$checkin);
echo date_format($dateObj,'Y/m/d');
```

**Output**

```
2018/06/22
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

this format is not recognized as a valid date by strtotime.. try using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) object, like this:

```
$dateTimeObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '22/06/2018');
echo $dateTimeObject->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$mCheckIn = $_GET['text_checkin'];//getting the check in date
$mDateObj = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y',$mCheckIn);//creating a date object.  
echo date_format($mDateObj,'Y/m/d');//echo or store the results in a variable
```

Output:

```
2018/06/22
```

Try that

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format will always be the same then you can replace the `/` with `-` which will make it a valid format for strtotime.

```
$checkin = strtotime(str_replace("/","-","22/06/2018"));
$textin = date('y/m/d', $checkin);
echo $textin;
```

This is probably lighter than calling date_create_from_format.
The flip side is that date_create_from_format will only work on this specific format.
If the format is Y-m-d this code will work too but date_create_from_format will not.

https://3v4l.org/Hkrop